# Appropriate Drawing Library for JBox2D

Tags: java, swing, drawing, lwjgl, jbox2d

I'm programming a JBox2D Application. Until now, I used the Graphics2D and the Swing library to draw JBox2D objects on the screen. But now it's getting difficult because I want to attach images and rotate Objects. If you work also with JBox2D, can you recommend a good Drawing library?

Thanks guys

Comment: [Slick2D](http://www.slick2d.org/) definitely jumps to mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great and popular Java game library with Box2D integration called [LibGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). LibGDX allows you to develop for the desktop, Android and the browser with the same code base. Their wiki article [A Simple Game](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp) is a good starting point for setting up the project in Eclipse and drawing something simple on the screen. You can read about their Box2D integration on [this wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/PhysicsBox2D).